# Rollback records executed in two separate Transnational code block in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I am calling two `Transactional` methods from my controller

**Controller Class**

```
@Autowired
DataService ds;

@RequestMapping("addData")
public  void addCasesDirect() {
    ds.functionA();
    ds.functionB();
}
```

**DataService.java**

```
@Service
public class DataService {

 @Transactional
 public void functionA(){

  -------
  entitydao.save(entitiy);
 }
 @Transactional
 public void functionB(){

  -------
  -------
  //Read Data Saved on executing functionA()
  //using EntityManager and NativeQuery
  -------
 }
}
```

The `functionB()` requires certain data that was inserted in the DB while execution of `functionA()`. Hence, I have used two seperate function instead of one single.

I want to achieve the two below things.

1. I need to get the data inserted using `functionA()` when executing
   `functionB()`
2. If `functionB()` fails, I want to rollback the changes of both
   `functionA()` and `functionB()`

I am able achieve the first point by using two separate blocks.But how can I achieve the second point.

Using: `Java 8`, `Spring Boot 2.1.7`, `PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. I suggest you to read database transactions. Instead of doing this:

```
@Transactional
 public void functionA(){

  -------
  entitydao.save(entitiy);
 }
 @Transactional
 public void functionB(){

  -------
  -------
  //Read Data Saved on executing functionA()
  //using EntityManager and NativeQuery
  -------
 }
```

You should do this:

```
@Transactional
 public void functionA(){

  -------
  entitydao.save(entitiy);
  functionB();
 }

 public void functionB(){

  -------
  -------
  //Read Data Saved on executing functionA()
  //using EntityManager and NativeQuery
  -------
 }
```

Notice the call of functionB(). You need to call functionB() from functionA(). And not from the controller. Then then whole block [ functionA() and functionB() will act as a transactional block.]. So, when any of those fails the insertion done by functionA() and functionb() will roll back.

Your problem is you are treating functionA() and functionB() as two separate transactional block. So, your goal is not achieved. Rather you should consider themselves as a single block.

Pardon my english :)

Comment: It addresses only my second point of rollback. I am still not able to retrieve the records that was saved in `functionA()` when `functionB()` is called., even after calling `functionB()` from  `functionA()` as You suggested.

Comment: I had them as a single block as `functionA()` only. But I needed the data saved in the earlier section of the `functionA()` in a later section of the code. Hence I broke them up into 2 functions. But still I am not able to get the data that was saved by `functionA()` in `functionB()`

Answer (score 0):

For (1), you can simply return the data inserted from functionA such that you can pass them to functionB when calling it.

For (2) , you can make both functionA and functionB execute in the same transaction such that any errors happen will rollback all the things that are done.

Something like below  :

```java
@Service
public class DataService {


     public Entity functionA(){
       return entitydao.save(entitiy);
     }
    
     public void functionB(Entity entity){

     }

     @Transactional
     public void foo(){
        Entity entity = functionA();
        functionB(entity);
     }
}
```

Then you controller method just calls `foo()`.